# Python, How can I stack a 2D array into a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, dimension

Now,i have a 3D(c) array and a 2D(b) array,i want to make a new 3D(d) array, so what shall I do? :

```
c=np.array([[[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]],[[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]]])
c.shape
(2, 2, 3)
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]])
a.shape
(2, 3)

d=np.array([[[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]],[[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]])
d.shape
(3, 2, 3)
```

Comment: i solved it  b.reshape(1,2,3), then d=np.vstack((c,b))

Answer (score 1):

i solved it.
 b.reshape(1,2,3), then d=np.vstack((c,b))

Answer (score 1):

You first need to `reshape` one of them, then you can use `vstack` or `dstack` depends on which one you want to use. For example I use `dstack`:

```
c = c.reshape((2, 3, 2))
np.dstack((c, a)).shape
```